# Deploying a Symfony application in FTP server using FileZilla?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, filezilla

I wanted to deploy a symfony application via FTP using FileZilla
so followed this [Tutorial](http://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony2/deployer-son-site-symfony2-en-production) but i got a problem:

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

> 3/3ConnectionException: An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>   in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 103
>   at AbstractMySQLDriver->convertException('An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)', object(PDOException)) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php line 133
>   at DBALException::driverException(object(Driver), object(PDOException)) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php line 47
>   at Driver->connect(array('driver' => 'pdo_mysql', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => null, 'dbname' => 'Symfony', 'user' => 'root', 'password' => null, 'charset' => 'UTF8', 'driverOptions' => array()), 'root', null, array()) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php line 360
>   at Connection->connect() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php line 429
>   at Connection->getDatabasePlatformVersion() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php line 389
>   at Connection->detectDatabasePlatform() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php line 328
>   at Connection->getDatabasePlatform() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php line 81
>   at ClassMetadataFactory->initialize() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php line 306
>   at AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('PFE\SiivtBundle\Entity\Utilisateur') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php line 216
>   at AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('PFE\SiivtBundle\Entity\Utilisateur') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php line 265
>   at EntityManager->getClassMetadata('PFE\SiivtBundle\Entity\Utilisateur') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Security/User/EntityUserProvider.php line 39
>   at EntityUserProvider->__construct(object(Registry), 'PFE\SiivtBundle\Entity\Utilisateur', 'username', null) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 3514
>   at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_User_Provider_Concrete_MainService() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2087
>   at Container->get('security.user.provider.concrete.main') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 3459
>   at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_Authentication_ManagerService() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2087
>   at Container->get('security.authentication.manager') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1909
>   at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_ContextService() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2087
>   at Container->get('security.context', '2') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1769
>   at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getProfilerService() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2087
>   at Container->get('profiler') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1786
>   at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getProfilerListenerService() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2087
>   at Container->get('profiler_listener') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 3962
>   at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->lazyLoad('kernel.exception') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 3930
>   at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->getListeners('kernel.exception') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 215
>   at TraceableEventDispatcher->preProcess('kernel.exception') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 107
>   at TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.exception', object(GetResponseForExceptionEvent)) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3037
>   at HttpKernel->handleException(object(ConnectionException), object(Request), '1') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2973
>   at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3116
>   at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2365
>   at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/web/app_dev.php line 28
>   2/3PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>   in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php line 47
>   at PDOConnection::__construct('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=Symfony;charset=UTF8;', 'root', null, array()) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php line 45
>   at Driver->connect(array('driver' => 'pdo_mysql', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => null, 'dbname' => 'Symfony', 'user' => 'root', 'password' => null, 'charset' => 'UTF8', 'driverOptions' => array()), 'root', null, array()) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php line 360
>   at Connection->connect() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php line 429
>   at Connection->getDatabasePlatformVersion() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php line 389
>   at Connection->detectDatabasePlatform() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php line 328
>   at Connection->getDatabasePlatform() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php line 81
>   at ClassMetadataFactory->initialize() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php line 306
>   at AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('PFE\SiivtBundle\Entity\Utilisateur') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php line 216
>   at AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('PFE\SiivtBundle\Entity\Utilisateur') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php line 265
>   at EntityManager->getClassMetadata('PFE\SiivtBundle\Entity\Utilisateur') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Security/User/EntityUserProvider.php line 39
>   at EntityUserProvider->__construct(object(Registry), 'PFE\SiivtBundle\Entity\Utilisateur', 'username', null) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 3514
>   at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_User_Provider_Concrete_MainService() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2087
>   at Container->get('security.user.provider.concrete.main') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 3459
>   at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_Authentication_ManagerService() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2087
>   at Container->get('security.authentication.manager') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1909
>   at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_ContextService() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2087
>   at Container->get('security.context', '2') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1769
>   at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getProfilerService() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2087
>   at Container->get('profiler') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1786
>   at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getProfilerListenerService() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2087
>   at Container->get('profiler_listener') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 3962
>   at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->lazyLoad('kernel.exception') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 3930
>   at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->getListeners('kernel.exception') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 215
>   at TraceableEventDispatcher->preProcess('kernel.exception') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 107
>   at TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.exception', object(GetResponseForExceptionEvent)) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3037
>   at HttpKernel->handleException(object(ConnectionException), object(Request), '1') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2973
>   at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3116
>   at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2365
>   at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/web/app_dev.php line 28
>   1/3PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>   in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php line 43
>   at PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=Symfony;charset=UTF8;', 'root', null, array()) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php line 43
>   at PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=Symfony;charset=UTF8;', 'root', null, array()) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php line 45
>   at Driver->connect(array('driver' => 'pdo_mysql', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => null, 'dbname' => 'Symfony', 'user' => 'root', 'password' => null, 'charset' => 'UTF8', 'driverOptions' => array()), 'root', null, array()) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php line 360
>   at Connection->connect() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php line 429
>   at Connection->getDatabasePlatformVersion() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php line 389
>   at Connection->detectDatabasePlatform() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php line 328
>   at Connection->getDatabasePlatform() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php line 81
>   at ClassMetadataFactory->initialize() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php line 306
>   at AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('PFE\SiivtBundle\Entity\Utilisateur') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php line 216
>   at AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('PFE\SiivtBundle\Entity\Utilisateur') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php line 265
>   at EntityManager->getClassMetadata('PFE\SiivtBundle\Entity\Utilisateur') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Security/User/EntityUserProvider.php line 39
>   at EntityUserProvider->__construct(object(Registry), 'PFE\SiivtBundle\Entity\Utilisateur', 'username', null) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 3514
>   at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_User_Provider_Concrete_MainService() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2087
>   at Container->get('security.user.provider.concrete.main') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 3459
>   at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_Authentication_ManagerService() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2087
>   at Container->get('security.authentication.manager') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1909
>   at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_ContextService() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2087
>   at Container->get('security.context', '2') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1769
>   at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getProfilerService() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2087
>   at Container->get('profiler') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1786
>   at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getProfilerListenerService() in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2087
>   at Container->get('profiler_listener') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 3962
>   at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->lazyLoad('kernel.exception') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 3930
>   at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->getListeners('kernel.exception') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 215
>   at TraceableEventDispatcher->preProcess('kernel.exception') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 107
>   at TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.exception', object(GetResponseForExceptionEvent)) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3037
>   at HttpKernel->handleException(object(ConnectionException), object(Request), '1') in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2973
>   at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3116
>   at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2365
>   at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in /home/skhirimed/public_html/dlll.net/www/web/app_dev.php line 28

Comment: You can add another grant for localhost. It is highly recommended to set a password instead of keeping it blank/null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have the wrong password for root mysql user or wrong user mysql configuration.

Check your passwords / permissions and try again.

```
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: no because i didnt set a password even if i set it the problem with change to ConnectionException: An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: You don't have a root mysql password?

Comment: Did you update the mysql password in 'Source Files -> app -> config -> parameters.yml' ?

Comment: no i dont have pass for root here is the parameters.yml

`parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: Symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: fr
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
    debug_toolbar: true
    debug_redirects: false
    use_assetic_controller: true
`

Comment: Are you sure you can access the 'Symfony' database at all using your current mysql configuration. Do you have phpmyadmin or if on linux can you access the database with: mysql -u root

Comment: i have wamp phpmyadmin 
and its working fine in the local
but after i deploy it with filezilla it seems that cant connect to the local database i dont know exactly what i must do

Comment: I would highly recommend implementing root mysql passwords as standard. Especially on a remote server (as I gather is the case if you are 'deploying' with filezilla). Anyway the database access is your problem. Fix that on the remote server and the Symfony2 error should be gone.